# Finding the share price of a company couple years from now using the dividend discount model (practice)

Tags: dividends, stock-valuation, discounting

A company is growing at a constant rate of 8%. Last week it paid a dividend of $3.00. If the required rate of return is 15%, what is the price of the share three years from now?

My initial thought was to calculate the present value, and then just compound it to a FV that is 3 years from now.

Here's what I did,

PV = 3/ (0.15-0.08)

and then FV = PV(1.15)^3 = $65.18

But this is apparently incorrect. The correct answer is 58.31 according to my book. Why is that?

Comment: ((3 * 1.08) / (0.15-0.08)) * (1.08 ^ 3) = 58.31, but I don't know whether or not it's correct because I found it by randomly plugging in the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most commonly used dividend discount models is the Gordon Growth Model (GGM). The formula of the GGM is:

P = D / (r - g)

where

- P is the current value of the stock.
- D is the dividend payment at the end of the current period.
- r is the required rate of return.
- g is the dividend growth rate.

In three years' time, D = 3 * (1.08 ^ 4) = $4.08

Plugging this D into the formula, we get:

P = (3 * (1.08 ^ 4)) / (0.15 - 0.08)

P = $58.31